# Magento 2.3 How to validate all checkout fields at once

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

Is it possible to validate all fields in the checkout at once? Currently, if you dont fill in anything, only the email field will be validated. All the other fields are only validated if the email field is filled. I want to have all fields validated at the same time, so the customer doesn't have to click the "Place Order" button 3 times before all validations have passed. See screenshot for visual explanation.

[image: blank email field]

[image: filled email field]